# where can I define the database/table name in atk4?

Tags: atk4

In config.php, I put something like:

```
$config['dsn']='mysql://user:password@localhost/project';
```

I guess the last parameter 'project' defines the database name in mysql.  So I created a database called 'project' with a table name 'product' in mysql and put the same name in my model

```
class Model_Product extends Model_Table {
    public $entity_code='product';
}
```

I tested on my local environment without any problem.  But when I upload my files to the server, it returns error saying that cannot connect to table 'project.Product'. (The only difference is the first letter of 'product' has been capitalized). So it seems that the codes go with the model name 'Product' rather than the table name defined in the model code.

I don't know why it happens, but I think the only difference is the version of mysql (5.5 in local and 5.1 in server side).  Is there any solution other than upgrade the server side mysql?  Otherwise, I have to manually change the model name to `class Model_product extends Model_Table` and search & replace 
`setModel('Product')` to `setModel('product')` everywhere.

Comment: model name shouldn't matter. It's really weird bug. Are you on Linux? Which code you try to execute that produces this error?

Comment: I don't think it is a bug...must be something wrong with my code or setting that I am too stupid to figure out...I am using windows in local and everything is fine.  But does not work out of the box when I upload the code to a linux server...very simple code there,nothing fancy...just first add('MVCGrid') then a few lines of addColumn() and finally setSource('Product')...the error says the table "project.Product" does not exist.  So have to change to 'Model_product' and setSource('product') to make it work again.

Comment: Bingo. Change setSource() to setModel();

Comment: Then why the code works fine in local...so weird...so the difference is setSource('TableName') and setModel('ModelName')?

Comment: Because windows is case insensitive and if you specify setSource() to agile toolkit 4.1, it will use sql directly to pull it from the table. It's really interesting coincidence that it worked for you. setSource have been in Agile Toolkit from 3.0 even before models were introduced. On Linux it can't find table with the upper case.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using setSource('Product') instead of setModel('Product').

Function setSource has been in Agile Toolkit from 3.0 versions, before Models were added. It allows grid to manipulate with database directly. The first argument for setSource specifies table name, so "Product" is used as a table name.

On your local machine you are running windows, which is non case-sensitive. Even if you select from "Product" it fetches data from "product". However on your server you are using Linux and selecting from "Product" can't find table with such name.

This is due to a fact that MySQL is using files to store tables for MyISAM.

Your fix is to use setModel() and don't use setSource until 4.2, when it's severely refactored.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  The thing is that, by default, setModel() shows every columns as defined in the model while setSource() with addColumn() can show only a few columns of the data with more functions like addColumn('wrap','Col_1','DifferentName')->makeSortable().  Is it possible to archive the same thing by using setModel('Model',array('Col_1','Col_2')) with some additional lines of code?  BTW: do you have any idea when 4.2 will be released?

Comment: Similar thing for the MVCForm...If I just simply add('MVCForm') with setModel('Model'), is it possible to use setFieldHint('Some Hint') for each form field?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use only some of the fields in MVCForm with setModel, and you can also add stuff like hints, it will be like this:

```
 $g=$this->add('MVCForm');
    $g->setModel('Student',array('name','level','classroom'));
    $g->getElement('name')
    ->setFieldHint('Full name');
```